# app crash when using multiple inout param in function

Tags: ios, swift3, inout

My application crash when i use below code.

```
var char : Character = "1"
var char2 : Character = "1"

func changeChar( char1: inout Character,char2: inout Character) {
    char = "b"
    char2 = "b"
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(char,char2)
    changeChar(char1: &char, char2: &char2)
    print(char,char2)
}
```

**Error:**

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x100e0ec50, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at PPlayerNew`ViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 340 (0x1000eeda8).
Current access (a modification) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001004b9a38 swift_beginAccess + 468
1    PPlayerNew                         0x00000001000ee960 ViewController.char.setter + 92
2    PPlayerNew                         0x00000001000eebbc ViewController.changeChar(char1:char2:) + 96
3    PPlayerNew                         0x00000001000eec54 ViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 436
4    PPlayerNew                         0x00000001000eef98 @objc ViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 64
5    UIKit                              0x000000018b3cc5c0 <redacted> + 856
6    UIKit                              0x000000018b439630 <redacted> + 44
7    UIKit                              0x000000018b43959c <redacted> + 92
8    UIKit                              0x000000018b641470 <redacted> + 556
9    UIKit                              0x000000018b633420 <redacted> + 528
10   UIKit                              0x000000018b64c7b4 <redacted> + 152
11   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001852312f8 <redacted> + 20
12   CoreFoundation                     0x0000000185230a08 <redacted> + 288
13   CoreFoundation                     0x000000018522e6c0 <redacted> + 728
14   CoreFoundation                     0x000000018515ebfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
15   GraphicsServices                   0x0000000186bc9010 GSEventRunModal + 100
16   UIKit                              0x000000018b419bcc UIApplicationMain + 208
17   PPlayerNew                         0x00000001000f0570 main + 76
18   libdyld.dylib                      0x000000018416d598 <redacted> + 4
```

But when i use single param function, like below. code is working

```
func changeChar( char1: inout Character) {
    char = "b"        
}
```

So my main goal is to use inout function with multiple parameters.How can i do this or what's wrong with my code?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re changing the property char in your func instead of the parameter char1.